# Dataframe for visNetwork/igraph

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

I am working with some shipping data which contains information on voyages being undertaken by ships. Each voyage has its own ID and typically a ship commences its voyage in some port, loads the cargo in the same or some different port and then discharges it in some port. Sometimes, the vessel may also have to wait at a port before loading or discharging the cargo. Additionally, the vessel may discharge its cargo at multiple ports. The first 10 rows of my dataset are as below:

```
structure(list(Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id = c(1228L, 1228L, 1228L, 1656L, 
1656L, 1656L, 1675L, 1675L, 1675L, 1675L), Imos_VoyNo = c(19L, 
19L, 19L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), ord_no_int = c(100, 
300, 500, 100, 200, 700, 100, 300, 500, 600), Fkey_Dim_PortFunction_Id = c("Commencing", 
"Loading", "Discharging", "Commencing", "Loading", "Discharging", 
"Commencing", "Loading", "Discharging", "Discharging"), PortName = c("CHESAPEAKE", 
"CHESAPEAKE", "IMMINGHAM", "BELLEDUNE", "PORT CARTIER", "IMMINGHAM", 
"AUGHINISH", "NORFOLK", "LA SPEZIA", "FUSINA"), Fkey_Dim_Vessel_Id = c(1179L, 
1179L, 1179L, 144L, 144L, 144L, 1124L, 1124L, 1124L, 1124L), 
    Date_Arrival = structure(c(978307200, 1511927640, 1513400760, 
    978307200, 1510578000, 1511956800, 978307200, 1511611260, 
    1513713600, 1515225600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Date_Departure = structure(c(1511945640, 1512267840, 1516425480, 
    1510489380, 1510765200, 1513359300, 1510665120, 1512283320, 
    1514903400, 1515664800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Latitude = c(36.45, 36.45, 53.38, 47.54, 50, 53.38, 52.38, 
    36.51, 44.06, 45.25), Longitude = c(-76.15, -76.15, -0.11, 
    -65.45, -66.47, -0.11, -9.03, -76.18, 9.49, 12.16)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id", 
"Imos_VoyNo"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:2, 3:5, 6:9), group_sizes = c(3L, 
3L, 4L), biggest_group_size = 4L, labels = structure(list(Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id = c(1228L, 
1656L, 1675L), Imos_VoyNo = c(19L, 16L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id", "Imos_VoyNo"
), drop = TRUE))
```

I am trying to visualize this information as a network graph using the `visNetwork` or `igraph` packages in R. However in order to do that, I want to separate the `PortName` variable into  `From` and `To` variables and maintain attributes of the Port Function, viz. Commencing, Loading, Waiting or Discharging. I tried in vain to use a `for` loop to achieve this by iterating over every unique Voyage ID. Not worth sharing the broken code. Any pointers or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What is the logic behind separating `PortName` into `From` and `To`?

Comment: While working with `visNetwork`, I will need a nodes data frame and an edges dataframe. For the edges dataframe, I need to have the `from` and `to` columns as mentioned here https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/

Comment: Right, but how are you determining `from` and `to` in your dataset. There is no `from` and `to` column, so what is the logic for determining the appropriate `from`-`to` pairs?

Comment: Like I mentioned, a voyage starts from a commencing port, to a loading port to a discharging port. So if you look at Voyage ID 1656, the vessel commenced at BELLEDUNE, then loaded at PORT CARTIER and finally discharged at IMMINGHAM. So `from` would contain BELLEDUNE, PORT CARTIER and corresponding values in `to` would be PORT CARTIER and IMMINGHAM.

Comment: Voyage 1975 has two discharge nodes. Can we assume that the order is given by `ord_no_int` ? That is, the ship went from La Spezia to Fusina?     Voyage 1228 both Commenced and Loaded at Chesapeake. Do you want a link from Chesapeake to itself or not?

Comment: Yes to both questions. A vessel can have more than one discharge ports. It can also commence and load at the same port. The ord_no_int specifies the order of activities it carries out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded the data that you provided in the question into a data.frame named `Voyage`.  Assuming that your data is sorted as in the example (parts of a trip are consecutive and in order), we just need to link the ports for the records that have the same `Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id` as the next line.

```
library(igraph)

Leg = which(Voyage$Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id[-1] == head(Voyage$Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id, -1))

FROM = Voyage$PortName[Leg]
TO   = Voyage$PortName[Leg+1]

Routes = data.frame(FROM, TO)

G = graph_from_data_frame(Routes)
plot(G)
```

[image: Shipping Routes]

Comment: thanks for the reply. This definitely looks like something I could work with. Will explore how to add aesthetics to nodes and edges.

Answer (score 0):

The following forces the pre-sort by `Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id` and `ord_no_int` which should enable a clean graph generation:

```
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id) %>%
  arrange(Fkey_Dim_Voyage_Id, ord_no_int) %>%
  mutate(from = PortName,
         to = lead(PortName)) %>%
  rename(PortFunction = Fkey_Dim_PortFunction_Id) %>%
  as_tbl_graph(directed = TRUE) %>%
  ggraph(., layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_fan(aes(start_cap = circle(4, 'mm'),
                    end_cap = circle(4, 'mm'),
                    color = PortFunction),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm'))) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), size = 3) +
  geom_edge_loop(aes(color = PortFunction),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm'))) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 3/5) +
  theme_graph()
```

By leveraging `tidygraph` + `ggraph` you will have flexibility in representing and adding aesthetics to the nodes and edges. For example, see what happens when you change from `geom_edge_fan` to `geom_edge_link`.

[image: Network Graph]

Comment: thanks for your reply, however I am getting an error `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 10
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In graph_from_data_frame(x, directed = directed) :
  In `d' `NA' elements were replaced with string "NA"
2: In if (class(newval) == "factor") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (class(newval) == "factor") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: I am not familiar with `tidygraph` and `ggraph` but they definitely look like packages I should learn about. Thanks again.